# How to perform weighted partition of Dataset in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a time series data set in Apache Spark, with each entry representing an event, with a type that I'll call `eventType`.  I want to partition the data and write to storage partitioned into days and `eventType` as follows:

```
dataset.repartition(new Column("eventType"), new Column("year"), new Column("month"), new Column("day"))
    .write
    .partitionBy("eventType", "year", "month", "day")
    .json("output-path")
```

The problem is that one event type `problemEvent` typically occurs 10 times as frequently as other, so I'm hitting limits on memory usage in Spark for certain tasks.  In order to reduce the size of those partitions I'm able to create an extra column `hash` which takes one value for all event types except for `problemEvent` when it takes one of ten values at random.

```
dataset.withColumn("hash", hashUdf($"eventType"))
```

And then I can partition on this value as well (`hashUdf` is a user defined function).   The problem with this is that when I write out the data:

```
dataset.repartition(new Column("eventType"), new Column("year"), new Column("month"), new Column("day"), new Column("hash"))
    .write
    .partitionBy("eventType", "year", "month", "day", "hash")
    .json("output-path")
```

I then have an extra directory `.../day=10/hash=uuid/part-....json`. I really want the same directory structure for the output with additional files in the directory:

```
 .../day=10/part-....json
 .../day=10/part-....json
```

I'm not certain what I've done here is idiomatic either, and the `hash` column feels like a bit of a hack.  Can someone suggest  way to achieve this - reduce memory overhead for `problemEvents` while retaining a nice output structure?

It doesn't particularly matter how the data is broken down between the files in a given directory, file size or number of records would be fine, but setting `maxRecordsPerFile` didn't have any impact on memory.

Comment: Suggestion : persist your dataframe, create 2 dataframes (one for problemEvents, the other for other events) and use two write logics: the nominal one for the otherEventsDF, and a specific one for problemEventsDF which will just partitionBy year,month,day and write to a directory named /eventType=problemEvents/

Comment: It's possible, I was hoping to avoid writing custom logic for this.  The files are going out to S3 so if there's not something in the Spark API to do it I'll probably partition the data then map the file names with that script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide the `hash` column to repartition and not in partitionBy to keep the same directory structure.

```
dataset.repartition(new Column("eventType"), new Column("year"), new Column("month"), new Column("day"), new Column("hash"))
    .write
    .partitionBy("eventType", "year", "month", "day")
    .json("output-path")
```

And you will get the same directory structure.

```
.../day=10/part-....json
 .../day=10/part-....json
```

You can also specify number of partitions in `repartition(int numPartitions,Column... partitionExprs)`.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I needed, going to run some more tests but it's looking good, thankyou